# Android Studio error java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

please help I can't fix the error

Error:Execution failed for task ':funDriveAdMob:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat.class

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nbuzovsky.wallify"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':sweetAlert')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':androidsaripaarmaster')
    compile project(':cropper')
    compile project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    compile project(':library')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: Stop using JAR files and your problem will be easier to resolve

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you have 2 libraries trying to use the same class name (DisplayManagerCompat).

AFAIK, Android Support V4 defines this class but you need to search and check which one is the culprit of the duplication.

Let me suggest as first step that you maybe wanna try updating all libraries to their very latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your build.gradle: `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')`